# My new raspberry pi don't boot

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I've bought a new raspberry pi with a power adopter (5V, 3000 mA). I've written the rabian(2018-06-27-raspbian-stretch.img) image in sd card(8 gb) using win32 Disk Imager. the red light is active, while the green light has an irregular blink. when i connect it to the screen i get "there is no signal".
Could you help me please?

Comment: Could you check [this page](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) to see if the blinking matches any of the patterns listed? That could help to troubleshoot what the issue is.

Comment: it is irregular and quick blink for the first 5 minutes after that the blink gets slower

Comment: Just to be clear - is the screen connected before you turn on the Pi? or are you connecting the screen afterwards?  Check your HDMI cable is good and that you have the correct input selected on your screen.

Comment: Try using Etcher https://etcher.io to flash the image (no need to unzip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your display is a bit quirky, at least to the Pi.

Look in the first partition on the SD card (it will be the only one you can see with MS Windows).  Find the file named `config.txt`.  Open it and add the line:

```
hdmi_safe=1
```

Now try and reboot.  For more information see https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt/video.md